# form input clears when I select an option

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel/livewire. I want to get the latitude and longitude from google map and show the value in inputs:

```
<input id="latBranch" wire:model="lat" val="">
<input id="longBranch" wire:model="long" val="">
```

Using below google codes and it works fine when the page loads:

```
...

infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
document.getElementById("latBranch").value = position.coords.latitude;
document.getElementById("longBranch").value = position.coords.longitude;

...

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("latBranch").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("longBranch").value = event.latLng.lng();
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});

...
```

But the problem is that when I select an option from below select then the longitude and latitude inputs gets empty:

```
<select required wire:model="branchCountry">
    @foreach ($countries as $row)
        <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{ $row->countryname }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

The above select option gets the country `Id` and pass it to livewire controller to load provinces as below:

```
public function updatedbranchCountry()
{
    if($this->branchCountry != '') {
        $this->provinces = Province::orderby('provincename', 'asc')->where('country_id', $this->branchCountry)->get();
    }
}
```

My question is that how can I keep the longitude and latitude in the inputs when the I select or change the option of the select element.

Comment: You can't set the value of anything with `wire:model`, either set it via Alpine/$wire - or you'll have to trigger an input event after setting it in JS

Comment: Can you provide more details that where to put Alpine or JS because I right now it works and it send the values to the input if I load first time to change the marker location. But it gets empty as I select another option from <select>.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I added the Longitude and Latitude in a livewire emit as below:

```
Livewire.emit('getLatitudeForInput', event.latLng.lat());
Livewire.emit('getLongitudeForInput', event.latLng.lng());
```

and then in livewire controller I used listener to get the value as below:

```
protected $listeners = ['getLatitudeForInput','getLongitudeForInput'];

public function getLatitudeForInput($value)
{
    if(!is_null($value))
        $this->lat = $value;
}

public function getLongitudeForInput($value)
{
    if(!is_null($value))
        $this->long = $value;
}
```

Then I used those values.